# What is the default location of PM2 log files?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, pm2

I'm trying to find out where **PM2** saves the log files by default?

I'm working with a **Linux Ubuntu 16.04** server and I've installed it globally with `npm i pm2 -g`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

pm2 saves logs to `$HOME/.pm2/logs/XXX-err.log` by default, where `XXX` is your `pm2 app name`

Comment: why doesn't pm2 saves the log date and time? i can't see it in ~/.pm2/logs/app-err.log

Comment: pm2 also saves timestamp, you need to first run command: pm2 start app.js --time and then can display logs with timestamp attached in prefix by running command: pm2 logs --format or pm2 logs --json

Comment: neither --format nor --json works for me. I tried `pm2 start api --time` and then `pm2 logs api --format` and no logs are displaying on screen

Comment: Syntax err:Remove your 'app name' from following command pm2 logs api --format

Comment: so i need to start the application without using its name? i'll give a try. thank you for the help! :)

Comment: now it's working. but without using --format flag. i just started the application using `pm2 start api --time` and then `pm2 logs api`. now i can see the time prefixing the logs. thank you again!

Comment: Where can I see the error message/error tree in pm2 logs. `~/.pm2/logs/xxx.err.log` only shows 500 status but doesn't show error

Answer (score 27):

I wanted to see the logs for different processes.  There is a [console-based UI](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#terminal-based-dashboard) for this:

```
pm2 monit
```

Extra tips for pm2 newbies:

- Launch multiple, co-ordinated, [instance per cpu core](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#usage) with: `pm2 start myApp.js -i max`

  - Beware the 'js' example of cluster configuration; it didn't work for me.  Try 'json' instead.
- By default, you need to leave user logged in to keep cluster running
- Handy commands:

  - `pm2 start all` (also stop / delete)
  - `pm2 list`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: This answer is related to the question. If someone wants to inspect logs then this answer is helpful.

Comment: The question is "What is the default location of PM2 log files?". Does this answer give the default location of PM2 log files? No. It's helpful, sure, but not if you're looking for an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 18):

Type `pm2 log` in a shell and you get an overview of the last 15 log lines and the last 15 error lines in realtime. At the top of these log lines, the location of your logfile is shown. You can also type `pm2 log --lines 1000` to show more lines, in this case 1000.

```
$pm2 log
$pm2 log --lines 500
```

To exit, just type `ctrl-c`

Answer (score 11):

A great way to get information on logfile location (and other useful info) is to do a "pm2 describe" on the process that you have running.  You can use this method running pm2 as a standard user or if you use it as sudo pm2.

Get the name or id of the process

```
pm2 list
```

use describe by either using the id# or the name

```
pm2 describe 0
```

Answer (score 6):

pm2 has two types of log files for every app that it runs, an error log file and an out log file.

The error logs are saved to `$HOME/.pm2/logs/XXX-error.log` or `~/.pm2/logs/XXX-error.log`

While the out logs are saved to `$HOME/.pm2/logs/XXX-out.log` or `~/.pm2/logs/XXX-access.log`.

Where XXX is the name of your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 status
```

it will show your apps name or id
say above command return apps name PN and id : 0
Then you can write following command in console

```
pm2 describe 0
```

Or

```
pm2 describe
```

In return you will see 2 tables
where you can see as below

```
| script path       │ /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.3.1/bin/npm           │
│ script args       │ --prefix /opt/da/pn run start │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/pn-node-error-0.log       │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/pn-node-out-0.log
```

You are actually looking for out log path.
error log path will be shown if you configured