# Unable to see the console logs in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, console.log

I'm developing a webapp in Nodejs that I host in EC2 instance in AWS. Unfortunately, there's a bug that errors out only in production (EC2) that I cannot replicate in my local environment but I'm unable to find the console.logs to find out what's the error in production and debug.

I have been trying to set Cloudwatch agents assigned to my instance, but I still can't see the right logs. Any suggestions or pointers? Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the node app?

Comment: With pm2 constantly running in the instance

Comment: Check the pm2 docs for where it stores logs. You might need to set it.

Comment: Seems like this addresses the default location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828017/what-is-the-default-location-of-pm2-log-files but it can also be set with an argument or environment file

Comment: Your comments were super helpful! didn't know the logs were under /home/ec2-user/.pm2/logs - Thanks!!!