# pm2 randomly stopping all processes?

Tags: node.js, server, pm2

pm2 is randomly stoping? all my processces every once in a while.

I have pm2 running 3 enitrely seperate apps and for some reason every once in a while all the apps just die. when i do `pm2 list` it says all the apps are running but when i check logs (i dont see any) and all requests to the web server just gets timed out until i run `pm2 start "app name"` or `pm2 restart all`. Is anyone else facing this issue or know why this is happning?

Comment: There is no PM2 logs generated at all? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55828215/188331)